# Add elements to jQuery array

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function that loops through some input controls

```
function updateInputStatus($el) { 
    // Declare an error array that will contain jquery selectors
    $el.each(function () {
        if (this.Validators) {
            var isValid = true;

            for (var i = 0; i < this.Validators.length; i++) {
                var val = this.Validators[i];  

                if (!val.isvalid) {
                    // Add this element to error array -> $(this).closest('.input-control')
                    isValid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            $(this)
                .closest('.input-wrapper')
                .toggleClass('input-ok', isValid)
                .toggleClass('input-error', !isValid);
        }
    })

    // Do something with error array outside of loop
}
```

All is good, however I also need to locate each $el's parent and check if any $el's are invalid - if 1 or more is I add nother class else remove any existing class. I can't do this until I've checked the entire loop.

I've commented the areas I need to add code but I'm struggling to get it right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I guess you can just add an error array and push the error elements into it.  THen do stuff with them in an each loop at the end.  Remember they'll be jquery objects when you act with them.

so something like this:

```
function updateInputStatus($el) { 
    // Declare an error array that will contain jquery selectors
    var errors = [];
    $el.each(function () {
        if (this.Validators) {
            var isValid = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.Validators.length; i++) {
            var val = this.Validators[i];  

            if (!val.isvalid) {
                var close_thing = $(this).closest('.input-control');
                if(!close_thing.hasClass('used_for_error'))
                {
                    errors.push(close_thing);
                    close_thing.addClass('used_for_error');
                }

                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        $(this)
            .closest('.input-wrapper')
            .toggleClass('input-ok', isValid)
            .toggleClass('input-error', !isValid);
    }
})

// Do something with error array outside of loop
    $.each(errors, function(key, value){
        //*do stuff with elements in error array*
    });
}
```

Comment: The only issue with the above is that it allows duplicates in the array - any idea how to avoid them?

Comment: @dotnetnoob  see my revised answer.  Basically, when you add an element to the error array, you also add a class to it.  Then you check each element to make sure it doesn't have that class before adding it.  If this function will run more than once you can just remove all these classes upon exiting the function as well.

Comment: Gotcha - the extreme flexibility of jquery is difficult to catch on to,

Comment: @dotnetnoob yeah, I'm having a hard time adjusting to a more strict language right now myself...

Answer (score 0):

to get $el parent you can just do:

```
var parent = $el.parent();
```

see here http://api.jquery.com/parent/